# LDAPS will not accept cert

Tags: windows, ssl, active-directory, ldap

Windows Server Datacenter Core 2019

I have been working on this issue for three days now and no matter what I do, I can not get this LDAP issue fixed.

We have a brand new domain controller in our org, and all I want to do is enable LDAPS authentication. This should be a simple process and for whatever reason it is not.

Using Nettools, it clearly shows that port 636 is open on this DC, so it's not a network issue.

I do, however, constantly get error 1220 in the event log:

```
LDAP over Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) will be unavailable at this time because the server was unable to obtain a certificate. 

Additional Data 
Error value:
8009030e No credentials are available in the security package
```

I do however very clearly have certificates installed on the server and they are on my local machine I'm testing from too. It just doesn't work. I've tried installing the AD CS role, nothing. Right now i'm using self signed certs and CAs from openssl on another machine, and even that won't work. The server just will not use the cert i'm providing for LDAPS.

Keep in mind, my testing is done from mmc.exe as this server is running datacenter 2019 core (no desktop)

Here's some errors I get with these certs:

```
This root certificate appears to be trusted by the remote computer. To ensure this root certificate is valid on the remote computer, verify this root certificate on that computer.
```

It should be? How do I verify this without a GUI

```
This CA Root certificate is not trusted because it is not in the Trusted Root Certification Authorities store.
```

Okay but it IS in the trusted root certification authorities store. What?

I even followed this guide step by step, nothing.
https://help.hostingcontroller.com/Enterprise/default.aspx

I should add, this is the bind error I get:

```
ld = ldap_sslinit("dc-prime.compasshealthcenter.net", 636, 1);
Error 81 = ldap_set_option(hLdap, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
Error 81 = ldap_connect(hLdap, NULL);
Server error: <empty>
Error <0x51>: Fail to connect to dc-prime.compasshealthcenter.net.
```

Genuinely no idea what to do next. Any help is heavily appreciated.

**UPDATE 1:**
I went thru the processes of removing all extraneous certs from my testing, removing the CA roles, restarting, and adding them back. Now I am able to connect with NetTools, but there's a cert chain issue it seems and I'm not sure how to resolve this. Heres the error:

```
Verifying the Certificate Chain
Building certificate chain
 Certificate chain count: 1
 Certificate Chain 0
  Element Count: 1
  CertContext [0][0]
  Subject Name: DC-PRIME.compasshealthcenter.net
  SAN: DC-PRIME.compasshealthcenter.net
  Not Before: 1/07/2021  14:44
  Not After: 1/07/2022  14:44
   Certificate has Errors: 0x1000040
ERR: 0x40 - The revocation status of the certificate or one of the certificates in the certificate chain is unknown
ERR: 0x1000000 - The revocation status of the certificate or one of the certificates in the certificate chain is either offline or stale
   Certificate Status: 0x02
     0x2 - A key match issuer certificate has been found for this certificate
  ERR: Revocation check: Failed, Error: 0x80092013
   Revocation Server offline
ERR: Issues with the certicate chain, see above
ERR: Certificate verification would have failed for this connection
Error: ldap_sslinit failed with error: Error: (0x51) Cannot contact the LDAP server
```

If I export this key to my personal computer and run certutil -verify I get the following:

```
Issuer:
    CN=dc-prime.compasshealthcenter.net
    DC=compasshealthcenter
    DC=net
  Name Hash(sha1): 55758060d1c853dbf76f17adb6e8a46007e2a017
  Name Hash(md5): 6c0e7ec0c8de04cb788a0592ab2c7124
Subject:
    CN=DC-PRIME.compasshealthcenter.net
  Name Hash(sha1): 81305be4b49289dd287b505b300ec5e107485203
  Name Hash(md5): f195def40686f8e61f3c8b7c7f5b9dca
Cert Serial Number: 1200000002e7565ff3f4f3b9d0000000000002

dwFlags = CA_VERIFY_FLAGS_CONSOLE_TRACE (0x20000000)
dwFlags = CA_VERIFY_FLAGS_DUMP_CHAIN (0x40000000)
ChainFlags = CERT_CHAIN_REVOCATION_CHECK_CHAIN_EXCLUDE_ROOT (0x40000000)
HCCE_LOCAL_MACHINE
CERT_CHAIN_POLICY_BASE
-------- CERT_CHAIN_CONTEXT --------
ChainContext.dwErrorStatus = CERT_TRUST_REVOCATION_STATUS_UNKNOWN (0x40)
ChainContext.dwErrorStatus = CERT_TRUST_IS_OFFLINE_REVOCATION (0x1000000)
ChainContext.dwErrorStatus = CERT_TRUST_IS_PARTIAL_CHAIN (0x10000)
SimpleChain.dwErrorStatus = CERT_TRUST_REVOCATION_STATUS_UNKNOWN (0x40)
SimpleChain.dwErrorStatus = CERT_TRUST_IS_OFFLINE_REVOCATION (0x1000000)
SimpleChain.dwErrorStatus = CERT_TRUST_IS_PARTIAL_CHAIN (0x10000)

CertContext[0][0]: dwInfoStatus=2 dwErrorStatus=1000040
  Issuer: CN=dc-prime.compasshealthcenter.net, DC=compasshealthcenter, DC=net
  NotBefore: 7/1/2021 9:44 AM
  NotAfter: 7/1/2022 9:44 AM
  Subject: CN=DC-PRIME.compasshealthcenter.net
  Serial: 1200000002e7565ff3f4f3b9d0000000000002
  SubjectAltName: Other Name:DS Object Guid=04 10 13 80 36 ee b9 20 0b 45 b7 e8 c3 43 b9 80 4b 5b, DNS Name=DC-PRIME.compasshealthcenter.net
  Template: DomainController
  Cert: 092eb7929b8eac83c44c3ae8e71b0034e176c23b
  Element.dwInfoStatus = CERT_TRUST_HAS_KEY_MATCH_ISSUER (0x2)
  Element.dwErrorStatus = CERT_TRUST_REVOCATION_STATUS_UNKNOWN (0x40)
  Element.dwErrorStatus = CERT_TRUST_IS_OFFLINE_REVOCATION (0x1000000)
  Application[0] = 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2 Client Authentication
  Application[1] = 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1 Server Authentication

Exclude leaf cert:
  Chain: da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709
Full chain:
  Chain: 092eb7929b8eac83c44c3ae8e71b0034e176c23b
Missing Issuer: CN=dc-prime.compasshealthcenter.net, DC=compasshealthcenter, DC=net
  Issuer: CN=dc-prime.compasshealthcenter.net, DC=compasshealthcenter, DC=net
  NotBefore: 7/1/2021 9:44 AM
  NotAfter: 7/1/2022 9:44 AM
  Subject: CN=DC-PRIME.compasshealthcenter.net
  Serial: 1200000002e7565ff3f4f3b9d0000000000002
  SubjectAltName: Other Name:DS Object Guid=04 10 13 80 36 ee b9 20 0b 45 b7 e8 c3 43 b9 80 4b 5b, DNS Name=DC-PRIME.compasshealthcenter.net
  Template: DomainController
  Cert: 092eb7929b8eac83c44c3ae8e71b0034e176c23b
A certificate chain could not be built to a trusted root authority. 0x800b010a (-2146762486 CERT_E_CHAINING)
------------------------------------
Incomplete certificate chain
Cannot find certificate:
    CN=dc-prime.compasshealthcenter.net, DC=compasshealthcenter, DC=net

ERROR: Verifying leaf certificate revocation status returned The revocation function was unable to check revocation because the revocation server was offline. 0x80092013 (-2146885613 CRYPT_E_REVOCATION_OFFLINE)
CertUtil: The revocation function was unable to check revocation because the revocation server was offline.

CertUtil: -verify command completed successfully.
```

Any idea what's gone wrong here? How do I identify what the revocation server is? From what I understand, that's the CA server I just installed and it's very clearly online.

Comment: Not quite an answer, so I will leave a comment. Seems like it might be a chain issue. Can you see if you have any intermediate CA servers you need to add? If so, it would need to be added to the Trusted Root Store as well. Thanks

Comment: @Technoob1984 It's a self signed cert. The server is supposed to act as the CA, which it does look like it's doing but I don't know how to verify that

Comment: Razeth, 
Someone had downvoted your question. I upvoted it back up. I think the downvote may have been for lack of operating system. You list the errors, which is why I thought it was fine. Please add the OS info, and let's see if that satisfies the Mods. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

The Operating System being used to host the LDAP Directory and the CA could be helpful in the future. Here is how I would troubleshoot:

Windows Commands:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/identity/ldap-over-ssl-connection-issues

Hybrid Environment Commands:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/windows-server/identity/enable-ldap-over-ssl-3rd-certification-authority

Linux Commands:
https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/How-to-test-LDAPS-url-from-Linux/td-p/226572

Certificate Troubleshooting on Windows (a little older, but it looked good to me): https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/ask-the-directory-services-team/how-to-troubleshoot-certificate-enrollment-in-the-mmc/ba-p/394973

Troubleshooting a CA on Linux:
https://forums.ivanti.com/s/article/HOWTO-Troubleshoot-certificate-issues-on-Linux?language=en_US

Comment: Feel free to ask more questions, I will try to help. I don't have enough info to pin point the issue, but my guess is that the client isn't accepting the certificate for some reason.

Comment: I just posted an update with new information

Comment: The Revocation List is talking about your CURL. Try just publishing it via https, might help. Let me know -

Comment: For your Certificate chain - Can you explain the chain? This is the intermediary to Primary CA. I can explain further if you need. Do you own the CA? Is it openssl, or something else?

Answer (score 0):

You probably already solved the problem by now, but here are some pointers, that might help others with the same issue.

The Event ID 1220, occurs because the DC is unable to find a suitable certificate to use for LDAPS.  The certificate, must support server and client authentication and be installed on the server under NTDS\Personal certificate store.

The second error is because the certificate that is installed, doesn't appear to be a self-signed cert or the root is missing.  A self-signed cert would have the following Status flags:

```
 0x4 - A name match issuer certificate has been found for this certificate
 0x8 - The certificate is self-signed
 0x100 - The certificate or chain has a preferred issuer.
```

With NetTools, if you select the Display Cert option the server certificate will be displayed in the standard Windows certificate dialog, which will also show if the certificate chain is complete.

This article has details on how to troubleshoot LDAPS issues with AD. https://nettools.net/howto-troubleshoot-ad-ldaps-connection-issues/

Gary.